# select using "=" and using "between" in Microsoft acces datetime which is faster

Tags: ms-access, select

i have 2 ways to select a big table on a certain date using this code:

```
select Per_Code,Date_Time from TA_Record_Info
where DateValue(Date_Time)=#2017-09-4#
```

and the other way is like this:

```
select Per_Code as nik,Date_Time as min from TA_Record_Info
where Date_Time between '2017-09-4 00:00:00' and '2017-09-4 23:59:59'
```

**I think if using the between will be faster. is that true? and why can it be like that?**

Comment: sorry, im using auto text. this is just a typo. I've fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering on a (calculated) *expression* (like your first query) will nearly always be slower since it will involve a full *table scan*.
If you have an index on Date_Time, the second query is able to use it, resulting on huge performance impact.

Comment: what do you mean about index. sorry im new in sql

Comment: do some research on "database index" !